# When i used OnTriggerEnter2D with Input.GetKey the input won't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

When i press the key the the scene won't load, when i remove the input statemen, it works.
can anyone help me ?

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.X)){
        Loader.Load(Loader.Scene.Shop);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `OnTriggerEnter2D` method is called only once when the obstacle enters the collider's area. As soon as the obstacle enters, the code inside this method is read, and it instantly checks for the input, that too only once. That's the reason the code inside the `if` statement isn't read.

To take input when there's a trigger, have a boolean that decides whether the input from the user has to be taken or not.

```cs
private bool isTriggered = false;
```

In `OnTriggerEnter2D` method, set this boolean to true

```cs
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    isTriggered = true;
}
```

Check for user input in `Update()` method only when the trigger happened

```cs
void Update()
{
    if(isTriggered)
    {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.X))
        {
            Loader.Load(Loader.Scene.Shop);
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to set `isTrigger` to false when the obstacle has exited the collider's area

```cs
void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
{
    isTrigger = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you man you saved my game. I will add your name in the credits i promise

Comment: Do share your game with me when it's done <3

Comment: Yes sir .......

Comment: You might also rather use `GetKeyDown` otherwise you trigger a new load each frame

Comment: no it okay for now, thanks for the info